# Traversing a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

I have some table rows:

```
<tr class='top'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='total'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='top'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='total'><td></td><td></td></tr>
...
...
...
<tr class='top'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='data'><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr class='total'><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

I have selected a row of class data.  Now I would like to find the row of class top that is in the same section and above my selected row.

Is there a jquery command that will do that for me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can move each of these sections to a separate tbody it can be done much more easily

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I am working with cards I am dealt.  You're solution below looks like it is working, I just changed the selector to ('.top') Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of prevAll() and first() like

```
var $tr == //tr with class data
var $trop = $tr.prevAll('.top').first();
```

Comment: Hi Arun - thanks for the response!  I think this will work, but my selector should be ('.top') instead of ('.data').  Also, the selection that is returned from prevAll will always be the same order?